# Cannot update specific records using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update specific `competition` using the `JOIN`. The structure of the `tables` is the following:

*country*:

```
id | name | iso
 5  Brazil  BR
```

*competition*:

```
id | country_id | name     |
 1      5          Serie A
 2      5          Serie B
 3      5          Serie C
```

*competition_seasons*:

```
id | competition_id | name  | update_at
 1         1           2019     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 2         1           2018     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 3         1           2017     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 4         2           2019     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 5         2           2018     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 6         2           2017     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 7         3           2019     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 8         3           2018     2019-01-15 00:00:00
 9         3           2017     2019-01-15 00:00:00
```

The goal is set `update_at` on `competition_seasons` to `null`. So I wrote this query:

```
UPDATE country n
    JOIN competition c ON n.id = c.country_id
    JOIN competition_seasons s ON c.id = s.competition_id
    SET s.update_at = NULL
    WHERE n.name = "Brazil"
```

the problem's that the query doesn't update anything. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should list the table you intend to update *first* in your query.  In this case we can reverse the order of the joins, and list the `competition_seasons` table first:

```
UPDATE competition_seasons s     -- target table, listed first
INNER JOIN competition c
    ON c.id = s.competition_id
INNER JOIN country n
    ON n.id = c.country_id
SET
    s.update_at = NULL
WHERE
    n.name = 'Brazil';
```

Note that the order of the joins should not matter here, assuming they are all inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is set update_at on competition_seasons to null.

I would expect

```
UPDATE competition_seasons cs
    SET update_at = NULL;
```

Is there some other condition that you are not describing?